# Extract mesh coordinates from a LaplaceSolution Plot

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, code-review, broken-code

I have made a code for the solution to a particular problem involving the `Laplacian`, and after plotting in 3D the resultant potential, I have tried to look for a way to extract points from that graph in order to later get the electric field produce by that potential, so I wonder if there is a way to do this, or another way to plot the electric field by getting the following solution to the `Laplacian`?

### This is the solution

```
a = 4;
f[x_, y_] := Sin[ArcTan[Abs[y/x]]]
g[x_, y_] := -Sin[ArcTan[Abs[y/x]]]
leqn = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0;
\[CapitalOmega] = 
  ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 >= 1, {{x, -a, a}, {y, -a, a}}];
A[x_, y_] := NDSolveValue[{\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\), \(2\)]\(u[x, y]\)\) == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == f[x, y], y == Sqrt[1 - x^2]], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == g[x, y], y == -Sqrt[1 - x^2]], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, 
    x == a || x == -a || y == a || y == -a]}, 
  u, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]]
ContourPlot[A[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
 PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, PlotPoints -> 20, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
Plot3D[A[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ViewPoint -> {0, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

---

[image: The ContourPlot]

[image: The Plot3D]

So I tried using this idea from http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/452396, by putting
    `Array[{##, A[##]} &, {10, 10}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]]
    Graphics3D[Point /@ %]`

But it doesn't seem to work, or I am using it wrong.
Does anyone has an idea of how to solve this problem?

Comment: Does `Array[{##, A[##]} &, {10, 10}, {{-a, a}, {-a, a}}];  Graphics3D[Point /@ %]` give what you need?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, it gives me two errors: InterpolatingFunction::femdmval: Input value {-0.444444,-0.444444} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. And, General::stop: Further output of InterpolatingFunction::femdmval will be suppressed during this calculation.

Comment: Are you sure about that `Sin[ArcTan[Abs[y/x]]`? It seems to me you should be using two-argument arctangent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
aa = NDSolveValue[{leqn, 
     DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == f[x, y], y == Sqrt[1 - x^2]], 
     DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == g[x, y], y == -Sqrt[1 - x^2]], 
     DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x == a || x == -a || y == a || y == -a]}, 
   u, Element[{x, y}, Ω]];

points = Array[If[RegionMember[Ω, {##}], {##, aa[##]} , ##&[]]&, 
 {10, 10}, {{-a, a}, {-a, a}}];
Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point /@ points}, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

```
Show[Plot3D[aa[x, y], Element[{x, y}, Ω],  PlotRange -> All, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",  PlotLegends -> Automatic], g3d]
```

[image]

Comment: Using `RegionMember` in this way can be very expensive. You could generate a `rmf=RegionMember[\[CapitalOmega]]` and use that in the `If` statement. But using a discretized version of Omega would be even better.

Comment: @user21, thank you. I will update with your suggestion.

Comment: @kglr is there a new command in MMA 12.2 for this task?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, i don't know if there is a new command that does this.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another alternative:

```
A = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, 
      DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == f[x, y], y == Sqrt[1 - x^2]], 
      DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == g[x, y], y == -Sqrt[1 - x^2]], 
      DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, 
        x == a || x == -a || y == a || y == -a]}, 
    u, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]]
```

We extract the values and the mesh (and from that the coordinates) from the interpolating function:

```
vals = A["ValuesOnGrid"];
mesh = A["ElementMesh"];
coords = mesh["Coordinates"];
data = Join[coords, Partition[vals, 1], 2];
Graphics3D[{Red, Point[data]}]
```

[image]